# Dynamic ng-switch inside of ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-switch

I am trying to create a switch based on a dynamic array of objects...

For example:

```
  <div ng-switch on="currentItem">
    <div ng-repeat="item in myItems" ng-switch-when="item.name">
      <p>{{item.name}}</p>
      <button ng-click="nextItem(item)">Next Item</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

And then in my controller...

```
  $scope.myItems = [{
      "name": "one"
    }, {
      "name": "two"
    }]
    // Default first item
  $scope.currentItem = $scope.myItems[0].name;

  $scope.nextItem = function(med) {
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.myItems.length; i++) {
      if ($scope.currentItem === $scope.myItems[i].name) {
        if ($scope.myItems[i + 1] !== undefined) {
          $scope.currentItem = $scope.myItems[i + 1].name
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Basically, the dom should render a div for each of the items, and when a user clicks the Next Item button, currentItem should be updated, and the switch should trigger based on that.

I am not seeing the first result as I should (nothing is being rendered). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/PF9nncd1cJUNAjuAWK22?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have forked your plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/A9BPFAVRSHuWlmbV7HtP?p=preview

Basically you where not using `ngSwitch` in a good way.

Just use `ngIf`:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in myItems">
  <div ng-if="currentItem == item.name">
    <p>{{item.name}}</p>
    <button ng-click="nextItem(item)">Next Item</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works properly. Thank you for that. I checked out what was rendered to the dom, and item.name was not being rendered with the switch so it must not be allowed. Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I've forked your plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/2doEyvdiFrV74UXqAPZu?p=preview

Similar to Ignacio Villaverde, but I updated the way your getting the nextItem().

```
$scope.nextItem = function() {
    var next = $scope.myItems[$scope.myItems.indexOf($scope.currentItem) + 1];
    if(next) {
      $scope.currentItem = next;
    }
  }
```

And you should probably keep a reference in currentItem to the entire object, not just the name:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in myItems">
<div ng-if="item == currentItem">
  <p>{{item.name}}</p>
  <button ng-click="nextItem(item)">Next Item</button>
</div>
```

Much simpler!